# IsPlainObject, thing?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Does this fn:

```
function isplainobj ( obj ) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call( obj ) === "[object Object]";
}
```

do the same thing as jQuery's: $.isPlainObject() ?

Comment: This should work under certain circumstances. Please show me your snippet where you are using this function.

Comment: im just using it in a general javascript utitlity plugin im working on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

Here is it's implementation:

```
isPlainObject: function( obj ) {
    var key;

    // Must be an Object.
    // Because of IE, we also have to check the presence of the constructor property.
    // Make sure that DOM nodes and window objects don't pass through, as well
    if ( !obj || jQuery.type(obj) !== "object" || obj.nodeType || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        // Not own constructor property must be Object
        if ( obj.constructor &&
            !core_hasOwn.call(obj, "constructor") &&
            !core_hasOwn.call(obj.constructor.prototype, "isPrototypeOf") ) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        // IE8,9 Will throw exceptions on certain host objects #9897
        return false;
    }

    // Support: IE<9
    // Handle iteration over inherited properties before own properties.
    if ( jQuery.support.ownLast ) {
        for ( key in obj ) {
            return core_hasOwn.call( obj, key );
        }
    }

    // Own properties are enumerated firstly, so to speed up,
    // if last one is own, then all properties are own.
    for ( key in obj ) {}

    return key === undefined || core_hasOwn.call( obj, key );
},
```

It checks if it's type is object, if it has or not a constructor and if its properties are own properties.

For example with your function an instance of a class will return true but in this case, because it has a constructor it will return false.

Comment: "with your function an instance of a class will return true" -- what class? `Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date)` returns `[object Date]`

Comment: @mpen If your constructor is an anonymous function will return ```[object Object]```. 
```const Foo = function () {}; Object.prototype.toString.call(new Foo());```

Answer (score 2):

According to jQuery source code here http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.isPlainObject, I have gone through all possibilities handled in jQuery's plain Object. The function you have mentioned is passing all the tests. And both performing in same way. Please check the below testcases

> isplainobj({});
>        true
>
> isplainobj(function(){});
>        false
>
> isplainobj(document);
>        false
>
> isplainobj(window);
>        false
>
> isplainobj($);
>        false
>
> isplainobj({});
>        true
>
> isplainobj(isplainobj);
>        false
>
> isplainobj({});
>        true

As per my understanding the object which has all own properties is a plain Object. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Edit:**

According to below lines in jQuery

```
// Not own constructor property must be Object
    if (obj.constructor && !core_hasOwn.call(obj, "constructor") &&   !core_hasOwn.call(obj.constructor.prototype, "isPrototypeOf")) {
        return false;
    }
```

Object should not have own property `constructor` and `obj.constructor.prototype` should not have `isPrototypeOf` to ensure it is not in prototype chain. Please have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf for more info.

Comment: ...it only fails if you call it on instance of a 'class' other than Object, as Kaizo suggests. But, in my point of view any instance of a custom class is, practicaly, plain object.

Comment: they should rename `$.isPlainObject()` to `$.isUntypedObject()` or something more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

This simple test should do it

```
  obj!=null && typeof(obj)=="object" && Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)==Object.prototype
```

//to ensure Object.getPrototypeOf

```
 Object.getPrototypeOf||(Object.getPrototypeOf=function(obj){
    return obj.__proto__ || obj.prototype || (obj.constructor&&obj.constructor.prototype) || Object.prototype
});
```

Comment: Is not cross-realm. Meaning that it will not work across windows or iframes.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery source:

```
isPlainObject: function( obj ) {
    var key;

    // Must be an Object.
    // Because of IE, we also have to check the presence of the constructor property.
    // Make sure that DOM nodes and window objects don't pass through, as well
    if ( !obj || jQuery.type(obj) !== "object" || obj.nodeType || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        // Not own constructor property must be Object
        if ( obj.constructor &&
            !core_hasOwn.call(obj, "constructor") &&
            !core_hasOwn.call(obj.constructor.prototype, "isPrototypeOf") ) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        // IE8,9 Will throw exceptions on certain host objects #9897
        return false;
    }

    // Support: IE<9
    // Handle iteration over inherited properties before own properties.
    if ( jQuery.support.ownLast ) {
        for ( key in obj ) {
            return core_hasOwn.call( obj, key );
        }
    }

    // Own properties are enumerated firstly, so to speed up,
    // if last one is own, then all properties are own.
    for ( key in obj ) {}

    return key === undefined || core_hasOwn.call( obj, key );
},
```