# Jquery.ajax, success: function(data) NOT returning a plainObject

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

According to the documentation of [Jquery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) success is a delegate (well at least I think it is, It lets you define the function to call) which will call a function and pass it a

```
PlainObject, String, jqXHR
```

But when I use the following code I am getting that that xml is NOT a PlainObject when I use alert to check.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dvContent").append("<ul></ul>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "message.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            alert(jQuery.isPlainObject(xml));
            alert(jQuery.isPlainObject($(xml)));
            $(xml).find('Book').each(function () {

                var sTitle = $(this).find('Title').text();
                var sPublisher = $(this).find('Publisher').text();
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
    });
});
```

How is this possible?

Comment: In jQuery, when you set the dataType, in some cases jQuery will parse the content for you automagically as that's usually what you want to do anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the nature of a dynamic language. Even though the documentation suggests that it will be `PlainObject`, this is not enforceable by the language. So because the content type which came back was `xml` and not something that can evaluated as a `PlainObject`.

The following question details a bit more about the `isPlainObject` function:
[IsPlainObject, thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531624/isplainobject-thing)

From the jQuery documentation, the crucial bit is that it will be

> **success:**
>
> Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>
> The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, *formatted according to the dataType parameter*;...

So by saying describing it in the method signature as `PlainObject`, they are saying that (if possible) it will be evaluated into a real javascript object, otherwise, you're on your own and it's the raw response from the server.

Comment: Thanks for that, coming from a strictly typed background the blatant lack of enforcement of type kills me, I assumed that it was ignoring the type and just putting it in there, I was just confused as to why the documentation lied to me. But through saying that it will try to get a plain object in there if at all possible makes sense, thank you.

Comment: I had the same reservations/thoughts when coming from strongly typed background too. I've learned to love it ... once you realise that *everything* is a dictionary (that's all objects are), it really is quite cool :)

Comment: Id'e say that it's an advantage to when you used delegates and void pointers, but in all other fields, I appreciate strong trying due to avoid error creep. But if you split the responsibilities up and make each function as lightweight and tested as possible that becomes less of an issue.

Comment: I still have to ask, I know it says `Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )`, but did you read what it actually says, "The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter ...", so it clearly states that the returned data will be formatted, and exactly how it will be formatted is clearly stated in the documentation for the dataType.

Comment: Only started using JavaScript recently, the main thing is that I see, it will produce a type, not it will produce a type according to it's data parameter. That's just more proof that it's just returning what it can and that it can do so due to the looseness of type in JavaScript.

Comment: @MichaelCrook - It's pretty straight forward actually, you can only send and recieve strings in an XMLHttpRequest, as arrays, objects etc. can't be sent over HTTP, as HTTP has no concept of things like that, but jQuery wraps that into a neat function called $.ajax, where you can pass objects, arrays, strings, whatever, and where you can set dataTypes of whatever you're expecting back and jQuery will parse it for you, so JSON strings are turned into javascript objects, XML is parsed as XML etc. That's whats really going on here.

Comment: @adeneo I updated the quoted section I made to highlight that fact. I'm not sure it would *parse* xml though ... it would just be a string if it's not valid JSON.